# Pandas: Selective replace using regex (Filter based on different column)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns in a dataframe:
Type(categorical), name(object)
How can I do below operation?

I want to update/replace name column data so that special characters get removed: re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', s)
only for those rows where Type = 'Attribute'

Comment: It seems to me that your question is lacking details. Could you please provide an MRE ([How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly which characters you're trying to remove so you might have to play around with the regex but does this work?

```
import pandas as pd

df.loc[df['Type']=='Attribute', 'name'] = df.loc[df['Type']=='Attribute', 'name'].str.replace(r'[^\w]', '')
```

i.e. use df.loc with a boolean filter

```
df['Type'] == 'Attribute'
```

for the rows and the column name

```
`name`
```

for the columns and assign it the new values with Series.str.replace.